# GeoServer authentication

Tags: geoserver, authentication

I created a user, password and a role, granted access to the layer 'myfeature' only for that role. Now I want to test whether the access restriction works, but I cannot find any documentation about how the parameters must be set for user access in a ordinary WFS request.

however, neither:

```
http://mygeoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=myworkspace:myfeature&
```

nor

```
http://mygeoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=myworkspace:myfeature&user=myusernamer&password=mypassword&
```

work, unless I disable the access restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is dependent on the tool you are using for the POST, but there are examples in the GeoServer documentation (e.g. http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/tutorials/digest/index.html).

In curl, it is `-u myusernamer:mypassword`, in wget, it is `--user myusernamer --password mypassword` (same convention as in the question).

In the browser, it will usually be something like:
http://myusernamer:mypassword@mygeoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=myworkspace:myfeature

For programming libraries, it will be different again, but that isn't really anything GeoServer (or GIS) specific, so you might want to ask on a programming-language specific site.

Comment: thanks a lot! But how would I do that with a plain url in the browser?

Comment: Updated answer to show browser example (still not GeoServer specific though)